# Is it possible to have a replica for MS SQL multi cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sql-server, azure, rds

I have a task where a Microsoft SQL database which is hosted on an AWS Windows EC2 instance and will need to have a replica on Azure. This is so that a team who manages the Azure infrastructure can consume the data with some analytic systems.

I work mostly on the compute side and am pretty weak with the database side of things.

My question is - how do I go about doing this? The SQL database can be moved from the EC2 instance to an RDS instance, if that helps at all.

Any input will help.

Thanks

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted? It's a valid question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider a third-party tool like [CloudBasic's](https://cloudbasic.net/case-studies/aws-rds-sqlserver-to-azuresql-powerbi-intercloud-dr/) that perform intercloud replication between Azure SQL Database and AWS SQL databases.

[SymmetricDS](https://www.symmetricds.org/about/overview) is another tool you can consider.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know if MS SQL can support this natively somehow?

Comment: @Sean no to my knowledge.

Comment: Understood. Thanks!